# Rendering text with QGLWidget.renderText after displaying 3d scene with shaders

Tags: python, qt, opengl, pyside

I'm writing a 3D application that draws a 3D scene and wants to overlay to this 3D scene some UI elements containing text. To do that I'm using Python and the libraries PySide and PyOpenGL. I'm using an NVIDIA card on ubuntu linux (proprietary drivers).

My paintGL function look grossly like this:

```
def paintGL(self):
    # Various clears...
    self.draw_3d_scene()
    self.draw_ui()
```

In the `draw_3d_scene` method I use custom shaders to display my 3d objects (mostly spheres). The shaders and vertex buffer objects are initialized in a different part of the code, and after calling initializeGL if that matters.

While in the `draw_ui` I try to draw the text in this way:

```
def draw_ui(self):
    glUseProgram(0)
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) # Black text
    self.renderText(100, 100, "Hello, World")
```

If I run the program this way, I obtain the 3D scene but not the text. If I comment both the shader/vertexbuffer initialization code (and of course the 3d scene drawing) I obtain the text correctly. While if I leave the shader/vertexbuffer initialization code and I remove the drawing part I don't get the text.

I expected that using glUseProgram(0) will revert me back to the fixed pipeline and let me draw the text correctly.

Do somebody know if I'm doing something wrong?

EDIT 1:

I'm trying to isolate even better the program and I think I found the solution (I still don't understand why this interferes with renderText):

The seemed to be related to glBindBuffer. When I used Vertex Buffers I forgot to unbind them. Now if I use:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
```

after binding a buffer I can finally see the text displayed

Comment: Are your vertex attribute array(s) (`glEnableVertexAttribArray()`) still enabled?

Comment: Yes, I can try disabling them and I'll tell you if this works

Comment: Also the end of your question looks like it got [Candlejack](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/candlejack)'d.

Comment: @genpfault thank you for the pointer :). In my spaecific test I'm not using glEnableVertexAttribArrays but glEnableClientState/glDisableClientState with GL_VERTEX etc... but the problem is still there

Comment: Did you add that bit about `glUseProgram(0)` or did I miss that due to not having slept for 40 hours? Anyway, clearly my answer was wrong so I deleted it. Just on that front, I did experience those symptoms in my code when I failed to unbind the shader. Qt seems to do lots of shadery stuff behind the scenes when rendering to OpenGL. I can easily see if you're leaving the shader code in a slightly incorrect state, problems will arise.

Comment: @HenryGomersall 40 hours seems like a lot! Anyway it was an incorrect state change as well but for BindBuffer, now it seems to be good!

Comment: Good stuff; I'm sure I encountered that one too :)